# libssh2 filtered out by modular filtering on RHEL 8

Tags: rhel, dnf, module

The `libssh2` 1.9 can't be installed from EPEL repository on RHEL 8.1 and newer (tested on RHEL 8.3):

```
# dnf --enablerepo=epel install libssh2-1.9.0
...
All matches were filtered out by modular filtering for argument: libssh2-1.9.0
Error: Unable to find a match: libssh2-1.9.0
```

Other EPEL RPMs can be installed without any obstacles.

How can I install the `libssh2` without downloading it and installing localy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest you can do is bypass module filtering.

Edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` and add `module_hotfixes=1` line under the `[epel]` section.

Done. The installation will succeed.

However the above can be too broad solution. The alternative could be to set `module_hotfixes` just in the command via `--setopt`:

```
dnf --enablerepo=epel --setopt=epel.module_hotfixes=true install libssh2-1.9.0
```

Comment: Works, however I'm afraid that it can have unwanted side-effects because it is set permanently. Probably better would be to use it as setopt cmdline parameter: `dnf --enablerepo=epel --setopt=epel.module_hotfixes=true install libssh2-1.9.0`. Please add this option to your answer. I consider it cleaner. And thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for how to address this in a copr, where I do not know how to directly affect the dnf invocation at the start of the build?

Comment: I got here because I needed solution for Posgresql14. Here it is: dnf --enablerepo=pgdg14 --setopt=pgdg14.module_hotfixes=true install postgresql14-server

Answer (score 0):

The `libssh2` 1.8 RPM used to be part of RHEL 8.0. However `libssh2-devel` and `libssh2-docs` were never included to RHEL and were provided in EPEL. That complicated the usability of this package. So as of RHEL 8.1 `libssh2` was moved to the EPEL as well. However it wasn't removed from `modules.yaml` metadata file of the repository `rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms`. That's the problem.

If you want to install the EPEL version, it is necessary to temporarily disable the AppStream repository:

```
# dnf --enablerepo=epel --disablerepo=rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms install libssh2-1.9.0
```

Then the installation then pass.

The modules metadata available on the RHEL 8.3 installation DVD ISO do not know the `libssh2` and when this media is used as repository, you won't face this problem.

Red Hat is aware of the issue:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1805260

The CentOS 8.1+ is probably affected as well, however I haven't checked.

Comment: This isn't correct. `libssh2` and `libssh2-devel` are available in both RHEL 8.3 and CentOS 8.3.

Comment: There is only `libssh2-1.8.0` in the RHEL. If you want newer version 1.9, you have to use EPEL. The RH itself claimes they removed `libssh2` from RHEL8 intentionally: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1660344

Comment: If you run `yum list available | grep libssh2` on a RHEL 8 or CentOS 8 system, then it is provided by the RHEL and CentOS repos. As 1.8 is the supported version from Red Hat , that is the one that should be installed on the system. If 1.9 is needed for something, then the best thing to do is to build it from source and add add it to the environment or else it could cause conflicts because other packages on the system will be looking for 1.8.

Comment: Well, in principle you're correct and I'd agree with you. However the support of libssh2 was officially dropped in 8.1 and if you need version 1.9 modules, which block the update, give you quite a headache. RH left the libssh2 in 'grey' zone... Rules for AppStream repository are not so strong as in case of the BaseOS.